# In a template literal, how to hide an element based on conditions?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've set up a template literal that feeds a list of events to the page. There's also a "Load More" button that pushes an additional event to the page each time the button is clicked.

I've already got a ternary statement indicating that if the events list is empty, a message "There's nothing here." will display.

...but the "Load More" button still displays. If there are no events, then there should be no "Load More" button.

How can I hide the "Load More" button when the events array is empty.

```js
const events = [
  {
    eventsLink: "",
    eventsTitle: "",
    eventsSubTitle: "",
    eventsText: "",
    eventsRegText: ""
  }
];

// const events = [
//   {
//     eventsLink: "https://dev.to",
//     eventsTitle: "Hello Dev",
//     eventsSubTitle: "Dev is here...",
//     eventsText: "Nextiva is proud to participate in Telarus",
//     eventsRegText: "Register Now"
//   },
//   {
//     eventsLink: "",
//     eventsTitle: "Hello Mozilla",
//     eventsSubTitle: "Mozilla is here...",
//     eventsText: "Held in Napa, the heart of the California",
//     eventsRegText: "Register Coming!"
//   },
//   {
//     eventsLink: "https://www.google.com",
//     eventsTitle: "Hello Google",
//     eventsSubTitle: "Google is here...",
//     eventsText: "Held in Silicon Valley, the heart of the technology",
//     eventsRegText: "Register Today!"
//   }
// ];

function eventsPageTemplate(event) {
  return `
    ${
      (event.eventsTitle,
      event.eventsSubTitle,
      event.eventsText,
      event.eventsRegText
        ? `
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 event-item">
          <div class="card m-1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">${event.eventsTitle}</h5>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${
                event.eventsSubTitle
              }</h6>
              <p class="card-text">${event.eventsText}</p>
              ${
                event.eventsLink
                  ? `<a href="${event.eventsLink}" class="card-link stretched-link">${event.eventsRegText}</a>`
                  : ``
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      `
        : `
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              There's nothing here.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      `)
    }
    `;
}

document.getElementById("eventsList").innerHTML = `${events
  .map(eventsPageTemplate)
  .join(" ")}`;

//load more functionality
let list = document.querySelector("#listEvents");
let items = Array.from(list.querySelectorAll(".event-item"));
let loadMore = document.getElementById("loadMore");
maxItems = 1;
loadItems = 1;
hiddenClass = "hiddenStyle";
hiddenItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".hiddenStyle"));

items.forEach(function (item, index) {
  console.log(item.innerText, index);
  if (index > maxItems - 1) {
    item.classList.add(hiddenClass);
  }
});

loadMore.addEventListener("click", function () {
  [].forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll("." + hiddenClass),
    function (item, index) {
      if (index < loadItems) {
        item.classList.remove(hiddenClass);
      }

      if (document.querySelectorAll("." + hiddenClass).length === 0) {
        loadMore.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.hiddenStyle {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container p-3" id="listEvents">
  <div class="row" id="eventsList"></div>
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="load-more-button mx-auto">
      <a class="btn btn-md btn-primary text-white" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
    </div>    
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: you have templates within templates, something seems wrong there

Comment: What do you mean? I'm only mapping to one template. Inside the template there is a ternary... but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you intended to do with `[].forEach.call(...)`.

The load more button's onclick handler does get fired. You need to reorganise the click handler logic:

- First do the querySelectorAll to find the list items.
- If there are none, then set button display to none.
- Otherwise, resume your existing logic of removing the hidden class for a subset of elements.

See working snippet below.

```js
const events = [
  {
    eventsLink: "",
    eventsTitle: "",
    eventsSubTitle: "",
    eventsText: "",
    eventsRegText: ""
  }
];

// const events = [
//   {
//     eventsLink: "https://dev.to",
//     eventsTitle: "Hello Dev",
//     eventsSubTitle: "Dev is here...",
//     eventsText: "Nextiva is proud to participate in Telarus",
//     eventsRegText: "Register Now"
//   },
//   {
//     eventsLink: "",
//     eventsTitle: "Hello Mozilla",
//     eventsSubTitle: "Mozilla is here...",
//     eventsText: "Held in Napa, the heart of the California",
//     eventsRegText: "Register Coming!"
//   },
//   {
//     eventsLink: "https://www.google.com",
//     eventsTitle: "Hello Google",
//     eventsSubTitle: "Google is here...",
//     eventsText: "Held in Silicon Valley, the heart of the technology",
//     eventsRegText: "Register Today!"
//   }
// ];

function eventsPageTemplate(event) {
  return `
    ${
      (event.eventsTitle,
      event.eventsSubTitle,
      event.eventsText,
      event.eventsRegText
        ? `
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 event-item">
          <div class="card m-1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">${event.eventsTitle}</h5>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${
                event.eventsSubTitle
              }</h6>
              <p class="card-text">${event.eventsText}</p>
              ${
                event.eventsLink
                  ? `<a href="${event.eventsLink}" class="card-link stretched-link">${event.eventsRegText}</a>`
                  : ``
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      `
        : `
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              There's nothing here.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      `)
    }
    `;
}

document.getElementById("eventsList").innerHTML = `${events
  .map(eventsPageTemplate)
  .join(" ")}`;

//load more functionality
let list = document.querySelector("#listEvents");
let items = Array.from(list.querySelectorAll(".event-item"));
let loadMore = document.getElementById("loadMore");
maxItems = 1;
loadItems = 1;
hiddenClass = "hiddenStyle";
hiddenItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".hiddenStyle"));

function refreshLoadButtonState() {
  const hiddenElems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + hiddenClass));
  if (hiddenElems.length === 0) {
    loadMore.style.display = "none";
    return;
  }
  
  hiddenElems.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (index < loadItems) {
        item.classList.remove(hiddenClass);
    }
  });
}

items.forEach(function (item, index) {
  console.log(item.innerText, index);
  if (index > maxItems - 1) {
    item.classList.add(hiddenClass);
  }
});

loadMore.addEventListener("click", refreshLoadButtonState);

refreshLoadButtonState();
```

```css
.hiddenStyle {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container p-3" id="listEvents">
  <div class="row" id="eventsList"></div>
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="load-more-button mx-auto">
      <a class="btn btn-md btn-primary text-white" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
    </div>    
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I see what you did, but the 'Load More' button is still there. It goes away when clicked. If the hiddenElems is empty, I don't want to display the 'Load More' button at all.

Comment: See updated snippet - extract the load button event handler as a separate function to "refresh" the button state. Then call that refresh function on the top level. But IMO you could wrap that in a react component so you can manage the state changes with respect to the list of events.

Comment: React is good advice, but we're not using React anywhere.

Comment: Additionally, when I load all the cards, I previously had the "Load More" button disappearing. It seems you took that function away. The way you have it set up, I have to click the button one final time in order to make that button go away.

Comment: Can you share an example involving loading cards?

Comment: Here you go - https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/ZELozJZ?editors=1010

Comment: Nevermind. I added another if statement to the first forEach loop. Here's an updated example: https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/ZELozJZ

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest to not use templates, put the elements in the markup (hidden) and clone them instead of a problematic string manipulation to inject HTML.

Not sure what your intent is with the global undeclared and your `loadMore` is about so I left it alone just to illustrate what I would propose.

```js
/*const events = [{
  eventsLink: "",
  eventsTitle: "",
  eventsSubTitle: "",
  eventsText: "",
  eventsRegText: ""
}];*/
const testEvents = [{
  eventsLink: "https//google.com",
  eventsTitle: "Google",
  eventsSubTitle: "Super Google",
  eventsText: "TestText",
  eventsRegText: "I RockReg"
}, {
  eventsLink: "https//google.com",
  eventsTitle: "Google",
  eventsSubTitle: "I am ignored",
  eventsText: "TestText",
  eventsRegText: "" // controls if it is used
}, {
  eventsLink: "https//google.com",
  eventsTitle: "Google",
  eventsSubTitle: "Super Google",
  eventsText: "TestText",
  eventsRegText: "I RockReg"
}, {
  eventsLink: "https//google.com",
  eventsTitle: "Google",
  eventsSubTitle: "I am ignored",
  eventsText: "TestText",
  eventsRegText: "" // controls if it is used
}];

function emptyNode() {
  let p = document.getElementById("clone-2");
  let eventItem = p.firstElementChild;
  let p_prime = eventItem.cloneNode(true);
  return p_prime;
}

function eventNode(event) {
  // console.log("Event:", event);
  let p = document.getElementById("clone-1");
  let eventItem = p.getElementsByClassName("event-item")[0];
  let p_prime = eventItem.cloneNode(true);
  p_prime.getElementsByClassName("card-title")[0]
    .innerHTML = event.eventsTitle;
  p_prime.getElementsByClassName("card-subtitle")[0]
    .innerHTML = event.eventsSubTitle;
  p_prime.getElementsByClassName("card-text")[0]
    .innerHTML = event.eventsText;
  let newlink = p_prime.getElementsByClassName("card-link")[0];
  newlink.href = event.eventsLink;
  newlink.innerHTML = event.eventsRegText;
  return p_prime;
}

function loadValues(eventItems, count) {
  let loadNumber = !!eventItems.length && !!count && eventItems.length > count ? count :  eventItems.length;
  for (let i=0; i < loadNumber; i++) {
    let newnode = eventNode(eventItems[i]);
    document.getElementById("eventsList").appendChild(newnode);
  }
}

function showEmptyNode() {
  let newnode = emptyNode();
  document.getElementById("eventsList").appendChild(newnode);
}

function toggleButton(show) {
  let button = document.querySelector(".load-more-button");
  button.setAttribute('data-state', !!show ? 'shown' : 'hidden');
}

function showEvents(count) {
  if (testEvents.length > 0) {
    loadValues(testEvents, count);
    toggleButton(true);
  } else {
    // array is empty so show the Nothing and hide the button
    showEmptyNode();
    toggleButton(false);
  }
  if (testEvents.length - count > 0) {
    toggleButton(true);
  }
  let list = document.getElementById("listEvents");
  let items = list.querySelectorAll(".event-item");
  toggleButton(items.length < testEvents.length)
}

 showEvents(3);
/* not sure what this is all about or the intent so commenting out since it does nothing

//load more functionality
let list = document.getElementById("listEvents");
let items = Array.from(list.querySelectorAll(".event-item"));
let loadMore = document.getElementById("loadMore");
let maxItems = 1;
let loadItems = 1;
let hiddenClass = "hiddenStyle";
let hiddenItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".hiddenStyle"));

items.forEach(function(item, index) {
  // console.log(item.innerText, index);
  if (index > maxItems - 1) {
    item.classList.add(hiddenClass);
  }
});

loadMore.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log('yup');
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("." + hiddenClass),
    function(item, index) {
      console.log('never happens');
      if (index < loadItems) {
        item.classList.remove(hiddenClass);
      }
      if (document.querySelectorAll("." + hiddenClass).length === 0) {
        loadMore.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  );
});
*/
```

```css
.hiddenStyle {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#clone-1[data-state=hidden],
#clone-2[data-state=hidden],
.load-more-button[data-state=hidden] {
  display: none;
}

.load-more-button[data-state=shown] {
  display: inherit;
  background-color: #AAFFAA;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container p-3" id="listEvents">
  <div class="row" id="eventsList"></div>
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="load-more-button mx-auto p-2" data-state="hidden">
      <a class="btn btn-md btn-primary text-white" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="clone-1" data-state="hidden">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 event-item">
    <div class="card m-1">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"></h6>
        <p class="card-text"></p>
        <a href="" class="card-link stretched-link"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="clone-2" data-state="hidden">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        There's nothing here.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you test this before submitting? This displays cards and the "There's nothing here." message all at once.

Comment: And it does that because of the test array that has one with and one without a `eventsRegText` value - which is what you had in your code.
To alter that to "not any" just check the array length as `if(!!testEvents .length)` to see if it does not have any (empty array) - I did a super quick alter to give more details on the array length part - does not cover what or how you wish to use the "load more" button - but that was not your question